# While saving SQL Server instance, getting "Unable to write into workspace setting" in Visual Studio Code

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-code

I am trying to save a new SQL Server connection into my Visual Studio Code. While configuring "SQL Tools" settings, getting the below error.

```
Unable to write into workspace settings. Please open the workspace settings to correct errors/warnings in the file and try again.
```

Can anyone suggest what is to be corrected here in order to save SQL connection.

Comment: The workspace settings are a JSON file, and this error typically means there is an error in the JSON syntax that needs to be corrected.

Comment: there are no errors/warnings in my settings.json file. Still not getting saved